# Confused about a getJSON GET parameter called "callback"

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

What does this (highlighted in bold) stand for in getJSON

```
$.getJSON('http://www.example.com/test.php?**callback=?**',...)
```

The **=?** in `callback=?` is what got me confused, because I thought it basically meant "go to the url provided and find the instances where a callback is issued".

The reason why I'm asking is what happens if I do this:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.example.com/test.php?**callback=hey**',...)
```

Does it look for a function in the test.php that is called hey with a jsonp callback or does the result of the callback got to a function in the script called hey?

I'm kind of lost.

Comment: So am I. Can you try to explain better what you want?

Comment: Sorry sorry. Thre has been an edit on the question, is that better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the request is being treated as [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> JSONP
>
> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by
>   the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the
>   discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

Comment: So does is the ? a significant part of callback=?, because I thought adding ?callback=... was what treated the request as jsonp and that the ? could be replace with anything.

Comment: The ? is a wildcard, it tells jQuery to generate a random callback name.  If you try it you will see something like `callback=jQuery1234512314151412` in the XHR response.

Comment: Guess :P  Read the jsonp section of the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), it will answer all of your additional questions.